# constant HDD activity

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

So this is my setup:

- Windows10 Pro on a SSD encrypted by Bitlocker
- 2 HDDs containing a StorageSpace encrypted by Bitlocker not automatically decrypted on Winodws start

Once I power up my PC the HDDs (or at least one) immediatly starts making HDD access noises. The HDDs sound like they keep being accessed in Windows10, too, even though drive usage is at 0% according to TaskManager, plus the Drives are not decrypted yet (so why acces them at all?).

I guess since the access starts at power on, it must be BIOS/UEFI related ? I'm using a Asrock B550M Pro4 Mainboard.

Edit:
The HDDs do not sound like they are broken at all, it just sounds like they are constantly reading or writing, which they shouldn't since they are not even decrypted yet.

Comment: Are they SMR HDDs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The system internals system monitor will tell you what is accessing the drive.  It takes some learning to figure out how to filter out everything else.. but well worth the effort.

Comment: Regular 3.5" HDDs