# Need help finding source of constant HDD activity in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

My issue is similar to [constant HDD activity](https://superuser.com/questions/1672506/constant-hdd-activity) but I have a slightly more complicated setup and can provide more details.

I've checked the usual suspects... nothing in task manager performance tab, nothing in task manager processes list, and nothing jumping out in sysinternals Process Explorer either when sorting by the usual disk metrics.  By 'nothing' I simply mean that disk activity is being reported as 0% on all my HDDs, outside of normal usage from apps when they actually use the disks.

But at least one of my HDDs is *constantly* chugging -- I can not only see the disk activity LED on my desktop case going nuts, it also loud and constant with the same sounding pattern pretty much non-stop once powering on until powering off.

My HDD configuration is as follows - I have an older 700 GB disk with big games on it that I don't play frequently and a storage spaces managed mirror array of two 14TB disks, which is currently showing as healthy and has no pending or ongoing operations according to the powershell commands I've tried so far. I have a couple SSDs too which are clearly not related to the problematic HDD chugging. Windows 10 Pro 22H2 19045.3693

If you have any ideas how to find the culprit of this constant HDD activity and how to fix it I'd love some help!

Comment: What does search indexing say that it is doing?

Comment: I don't have search indexing turned on for any drives.

Comment: Old age physical drive noises.

Comment: you could try diskmon, but I would check the SMART stats on all the disks. when the disk writes data from its write-cache, it will cause physical activity that the OS doesn't see as I/O, but I'd be surprised if you had that much pending data to write. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/diskmon

Comment: Could be the windows swap file but usually that is on the same drive as windows by default.    Given how cheap 1tb ssd are especially good samsung 860/870 evo I would just replace the 700gb with 1tb ssd.  You could simply shutdown the PC and disconnect the 700gb drive for 10-20min boot the computer as see if the problem persists, if the noise stops with the 700gb drive disconnected  you found the problem drive.

Comment: @cybernard, If the HDD is constantly churning, the SSD would have a short service life. Unlike an HDD, each cell of an SSD has a finite number of writes cycles.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  That assumes that the noises aren't coming from bearing failure or other mechanical issues from a drive, based on small capacity, that must be 10+ years old.  Also it assumes the files are being written to and not mostly read from because reading doesn't cause as much wear as writing.  Also SSD have DRAM cache which reduces the actual number of read/write actions of the NAND flash sees.   The 860 evo 1tb is  600 TBW, and even more for larger drives up to 2400tbw.

Comment: Ya I don't want to replace the HDD with a SSD if I don't know why all this activity is occurring.

Also, the drives are all still working great and SMART says they're healthy.  I see no reason to replace them, I just want to stop the constant chugging.

Comment: @cybernard - I see activity in diskmon (thank you!) but I can't figure out where it's coming from - how can I use this tool to see why the activity is occurring?

Comment: I usually use process monitor.  https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessMonitor.zip    Please make sure you use the filter to limit the output to the drive in question.  If you don't use the filter your screen will fill with 10,000 entries in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

*Task Manager* is the correct tool to show disk use, but you need to add columns to show drive I/O, and the path to the executable using it.

[image: Show Disk I/O]

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to open *Task Manager*.
- Open the *Details* tab.
- Right-click on the column header and choose *Select columns*.
- Add *I/O reads* and *I/O writes*, *Image path name*, and perhaps others, to show what is using the disk drives.

The numbers change **as the disk is being accessed**, so look for continual *change* in the numbers, rather than one application using a large amount of I/O. For example, [KeepAliveHD](https://github.com/stsrki/KeepAliveHD) is a small program which I find useful to keep an external HDD from entering sleep mode after a few seconds of inactivity. It works by writing, and overwriting, just a few bytes of data to a text file, every few seconds. Not a lot of I/O, but it keeps the disk running.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the view I was talking about when I said "task manager shows nothing".  There is no significant I/O read or write numbers that increment while the sound / activity is happening.  I can have no apps open at all, and the sound/activity is still there.